# Change log level for phantom embedded Cassandra

Tags: scala, logging, sbt, phantom-dsl, embedded-cassandra

In my Scala project I'am using the `phantom-sbt` plugin in order to start embedded Cassandra. The problem is, this plugin is pretty verbose - all cassandra logs will be written to stdout.

I've seen on `phantom` github page, they are using log4j to configure all loggers. But it seems not to work (at least for me). I've set all loggers in the log4j.xml on 'ERROR', but it has no effect.

How should I change log level for all cassandra loggers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `logback-test.xml` inside `/src/test/resources` wherever you are running the embedded Cassandra. Then you can easily turn off individual loggers or set them to the appropriate levels.

Take this as an example configuration:

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>

<logger name="com.datastax.driver.core" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="io.netty" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.cassandraunit" level="ERROR"/>
```